# No cmake config file in gaussian process package

Tags: catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi i want to use gaussian process for obstacle prediction but i am not able to integrate gaussian_process package provided by freiburg_tools with my prediction package as this package doesn't have any cmake config file. Is there any way around it ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174484/no-cmake-config-file-in-gaussian-process-package/) by [akhil](https://answers.ros.org/users/2787/akhil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2014-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Gaussian_process still uses rosbuild and you tagged your question with catkin, so I guess you are using catkin.

Catkin packages can't depend on rosbuild packages.

You have two options:

1. Port gaussian_process to catkin (see the [migration guide](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild))
2. Port your package to rosbuild (less cool)

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [akhil](https://answers.ros.org/users/2787/akhil/) on 2014-06-23**:
thanks for your reply and yes I am using catkin i will try to port gaussian process to catkin ..

**Comment by [akhil](https://answers.ros.org/users/2787/akhil/) on 2014-06-24**:
hey i migrated the gaussian processs package but im not able to include headers files from this package in my prediction package i tried using the include_directories flag but it's not working i had to give the full path of header file to include it .